Direction of Projection Landing on the Outermost Vertex of a Bounded Convex Polyhedron
Let $ C \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a bounded convex polyhedron located in the nonnegative orthant. Define the outermost vertex of it as $ \mathbf{v}^*=(v^*_1, \dots, v^*_n)^\top $ and $v^*_1 > v^*_2 > \dots > v^*_n$, where:

$ v^*_1 = \max_{\mathbf{x} \in C, i=1,\dots,n} x_i $,
$ v^*_2 = \max_{\mathbf{x} \in C, x_i = v^*_1, i\neq j=1,\dots,n} x_j $,
$ v^*_3 = \max_{\mathbf{x} \in C, x_i = v^*_1, x_j = v^*_2, i\neq j \neq k=1,\dots,n} x_k $,
And so forth.

Assuming these maximums are reached in this specific order (i.e., $ \mathbf{v}^* \in C $).
Intuition:
If I project a point moving along some direction $ \mathbf{d}^* $ in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and let this point go infinitely far in that direction, the orthogonal projection on $ C $ should converge to $ \mathbf{v}^* $. I aim to find this direction $ \mathbf{d}^* $ based on information about $ \mathbf{v}^* $ or other relevant factors.
Question:
Is it possible to define a function $ \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{d}^*, k) $ in $ \mathbb{R}^n $, where $ k $ is a natural number, such that as $ k $ goes to infinity, the orthogonal projection $ P_C(\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{d}^*, k)) $ approaches $ \mathbf{v}^* $? How would $ \mathbf{d}^* $ be determined algebraically?
